# Exporting Keras LSTM without Dropout layers for tensorflow/serving

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, tensorflow-serving

I noticed that when deploying a Keras LSTM model with tensorflow/serving docker container, a call to `model:predict` will return inconsistent values for same inputs.
After some research it seems that it is the Dropout layers that cause the problem.

What is the correct way to export/save a model *without* the Dropout layers to serve it with tensorflow/serving?

Comment: Where did you read that the Dropout layers are the problem? And how did you export the model?

Comment: I exported the model with `model.save('/path/')`. I found some github issues pointing to the dropout layers as the potential culprits and confirmed with a model without Dropout that returns consistent predictions for the same inputs.

Comment: No, Dropout is just a symptom, not the cause, you probably did not export the model correctly by setting the learning phase with K.set_learning_phase(0) as specified in https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#exporting-a-model-with-tensorflow-serving

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy if you add it as answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to fiddle with the Dropout layers, your behavior happens because the model is not correctly exported.

Before exporting the model to a tensorflow-only format, you should set the `learning_phase` to zero, indicating that the exported model should work in inference/testing mode:

```
import keras.backend as K
K.set_learning_phase(0)
```

If this is not done, then the exported model behaves as if it was in training, where Dropout is then not working as expected. You can find more details at the [Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#exporting-a-model-with-tensorflow-serving).